# Time required to traverse a tunnel through the centre of a planet

Tags: newtonian-gravity

> There is a tunnel along the diameter of a uniform planet of mass $M$ and radius $R$. A particle is projected toward the centre with speed equal to the orbital speed of a satellite in a circular orbit just grazing the surface of the planet. Determine the time after which the particle reaches the the other end of the tunnel for the first time.

I don't know why is it that the required time is half the time of revolution in an orbit of radius $R$. I know that the time period is independent of the eccentricity of the elliptical orbit, but here the degenerate ellipse along which the particle is projected continues outside the planet too

Comment: @user638473 " time after which the particle reaches the the other end of the tunnel for the first time  is the same as the time of revolution in an orbit of radius R" are you sure you are not missing a factor of 2 somewhere?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes it does, thanks.

Comment: @aditya_stack Oops. You're right, I meant to say half of that.